# Definition of a bridge

Tags: graph-theory

Are there two definition of a bridge? One that is an edge, when removed increases the number of components of a graph and another which is used the algorithm of demoucron(1964) in checking whether a graph is planar or not?

Thanks.

Comment: I have seen the first def'n referred to as an isthmus.

Comment: Yes, there is at least two uses of the word ‘bridge’ in graph theory.